# Meaning of "Uptempo" music vs "upbeat" music (and their opposites)

Tags: terminology, genre

Can the expression "uptempo music" be used as a synonym for "upbeat music"? Please note that I'm not referring to the music theory meaning of the term upbeat (the beat preceding a bar), but rather the term used by music critics todesribe the general mood/feel of a tune. SO, ultimately, is the following correct: ubeat:downbeat=uptempo:downtempo?

ps: the meaning of upbeat(solely) was already discussed here: [What is "Upbeat Music"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54763/what-is-upbeat-music/71507?noredirect=1#comment112473_71507)

Comment: Upbeat is usually the beat *before* the first beat of the bar...

Comment: yeah sry i was so concentrated on the rest of the question that i inverted the two.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider them synonymous.

`Upbeat`, other than the strictly musical definition of the last beat of the bar, is an expression of positive sentiment & is not exclusively used to describe music. e.g. [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upbeat) & [these synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/upbeat).

`Up-tempo music`, on the other hand, describes a fast tempo. It *may* also imply positive mood (can't find the example i saw of this implication the i saw this week, damn!), but generally not. e.g. [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up-tempo)

[added]
Now, as for your identity relation: i don't think that hold either. According to a quick bit of research that i did:

- `downtempo` & `downbeat` refer to a style of ambient music;
- `downbeat` is the first beat of the bar (as you already observed), & by analogy it also applies to the beginning of a rehearsal or performance;
- `downbeat` is the opposite of `upbeat` in the sense of meaning a negative mood as opposed to the positive upbeat mood.

So while `upbeat` & `downbeat` are opposites in terms of mood (positive/negative) & complements in terms of positions in the bar (last/first), `uptempo` & `downtempo` don't seem to have a similar relationship. Further, while the words `downbeat` & `downtempo` refer to a style of ambient electronica, they are not interchangeable in any other use.

In summary: `upbeat` & `uptempo` are not synonyms; `downbeat` & `downtempo` are both names for a style of music; `upbeat mood` is the opposite of `downbeat mood`; `uptempo` & `downtempo` aren't really antonyms as the former is a general description & the latter is a specific style.

Comment: And how about their anthynonyms?

Comment: @cloverblack -- added a discussion of antonyms. You might also want to look at the [english.se] for answers to this language question, or even ask it there, too.

Comment: Downtempo also refers to slower tempo but not ambient in my experience. Think DJ Shadow, almost anything in the trip-hop genre, DJ Spooky, Kruder & Dorfmeister. Unlike faster 110 to 130 uptempo dance music, downtempo is typically hip-hop BPM or exactly half that of standard drum and bass or jungle. People will often mix downtempo into a set of drum and bass or jungle for transitions and to help build intensity when switching back to full BPM. While ambient usually has no drum beat downtempo often has a strong drum beat but slower (75 to 95 bpm) than most dance music (110 to 140).